# How to skip to next line of MDTextField when the first one reaches the border with text. KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hi I am trying to skip to the next line of a MDTextField when the text hits the side of the field like this:[image: Picture of the text hitting the side]

Here is a picture of the text being cut off, when this happens I want it to go to the next line:

[image: Picture of the text being cut off]

I have looked in the KivyMD docs and could not spot anything hope someone can figure this out maybe you have dealt with this before. Anyway I hope you can solve this.

Comment: If your text includes some spaces, The `MDTextInput` will wrap to another line. Is your input text just one long string with no spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this to work you must set multiline to true in kivy